# Can "date" variable be used in PCA?

Tags: r, pca

I'm doing the research on data from the waterworks and having a huge datasets with different measurements. They are all were conducted on certain days through many years. When I'm driving the PCA only on measurements its looking good, but I also wanna know if these measurements are having time trend connections as its the mainly reason why im doing PCA.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that this is the appropriate way to find out time  trends. However, what you could try is to create dummies for the dates you want to test, e.g. for each month or year or quarter etc. Then you could see their importance in the PCA analysis.